# Input Verifier on JTextField returns incorrect

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, inputverifier

This is my code, I have two text fields, `tf1` and `tf2` :

```
public class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {
@Override
public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
    String name = input.getName();
    if (name.equals("tf1")) {
        System.out.println("in tf1");
        String text = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
        if (text.matches(".*\\d.*")) return false;       // have digit
    }
    else if (name.equals("tf2")) {
        System.out.println("in tf2");
        String text = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
        if (isNumeric2(text)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isNumeric2(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static class Tester extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField tf1, tf2;
    JButton okBtn;

    public Tester() {
        add(panel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Tester();
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        okBtn = new JButton("Ok");
        okBtn.addActionListener(this);
        tf1 = new JTextField(10);
        tf1.setName("tf1");
        tf2 = new JTextField(10);
        tf2.setName("tf2");
        tf1.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
        tf2.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
        panel.add(tf1);
//            panel.add(tf2);
        panel.add(okBtn);
        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MyInputVerifier inputVerifier = new MyInputVerifier();
        if (e.getSource() == okBtn) {
            if (inputVerifier.verify(tf2)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "True in tf2");
            } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "False in tf2");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Output:

I enter 10

```
on joption pane: false in tf2
on console: in tf1
            in tf2
```

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? Anyway, manually verifying the field with a new InputVerifier looks fishy, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kleopatra i enter `10`, So in should returns true and show `True in tf2` and also not show `in tf1` in console!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) the `verify()` method is called when the `JTextField` loose focus. In your code, `tf1` loose focus when you click on okbtn. So the `verify()` method of tf1 is called and print `in tf1`.

In the actionPerformed, you call explicitely the `verify()` method so `in tf2` is printed. Since `tf2` is empty (i.e. the line where you add it in the JPanel is commented): the `JOptionPane` display `false in tf2`

I hope those explainations will help you to fix your code. You must understand that you don't need to call `verify()` yourself, it will be called automatically by the swing framework when the field loose the focus.